# How can I avoid the high commission of paypal?

Tags: api, paypal, payment

I'm sorry guys,
probably it's not here the right place to talk about that by stackoverflow community is the best and I always find solutions here and not in other sides.
I'm really pissed for this, I developed the payment by the Api of paypal, for me was super difficult due also to the paypal website so confused with new and old versions, all so boring, and now that finally I got, from all the payments of my clients Paypal got 5% of commission??
Are you kidding me??
Do you know how Can I avoid this? or another way to get money without to lose a lot of as in this way?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

PayPal transaction fees are [advertised here](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant-fees).  They vary by country, some are on the lower end such as 2.59% for credit cards for internet purchases; other places have higher rates like 5.4%. So if you want to compare with other services, those will similarly depend on which country you are receiving the payment in.

---

While probably not relevant to your case (since you mention 5%), PayPal's US rates were recently changed in some interesting ways. You can read about those US changes and see graphs on how they stack up [here](https://newsroom.paypal-corp.com/2021-06-18-Upcoming-Changes-for-Some-US-Businesses).